# Microsoft Word suddenly lose the whole formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, documents

I was working on a document in MS Word when all of a sudden the whole formatting went lost. I don't remember the exact sequence of operations I did, and I understand this could be a problem, but I tried the undo button up to the first operation and still the formatting was lost. I tried to exit without saving but still, opening it again gave the wrong formatting. How can it be? Is there a way to get the original formatting back?

By formatting I mean, data into tables, table structures, alignment, index and everything in the document. I tried the "Change style" trick but that recovered only the text, tables, figures and the chapters' superscript at the beginning of every page are still formatted in the wrong way.

I even tried to open the document from another PC but still, formatting was lost.

The only fishy operation I remember is that I converted the document in a .pdf, though the .docx is still there untouched it doesn't have the formatting.

I'm using MS Word 2011 and tried even MS Word 2007.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Word 2011 and 2007 - So you're editing on both the Mac and Windows versions?

Comment: What exactly had happened to the tables? Did they only had lost their layout (fonts, border colour, cell orientation) or also their structure (i.e. they are no longer tables, but a chunk text)? This might be a clue to what have happened.

Comment: Yes I'm editing on both the Mac and the Windows versions. Tables, and text in general have lost their shape, for example Chapter became C (newline) hapter and stuff like that, the problems are only misalignment and bold... there are no such things as having a plain text document